# Top tag - Reputation Change since last visit

Tags: bug, reputation

The `+10` won't clear from the top tag section of my profile after visiting the reputation tab.

Chrome 44 / Windows 7.

[image: Profile screen]

Comment: Shall we blame the cache?

Comment: I thought it might be cache however it does clear from the right had side of total rep, and I've never seen this before so I assume to a new feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the cache is to blame.

The reputation is cleared after 10 minutes. This is different from the overall reputation that is instantly cleared. (this seems a bug to me, or at least confusing).

It also works the other way around: the +10 I just received is added to the total rep, but not to the tag reputation:

[image]

Comment: Agreed. It has cleared now but it very jarring that one clears and the other does not.